# Spectrum of tridiagonal block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

I have the following $4n \times 4n$ block tridiagonal matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
M_{1} && -M_{2} && 0 && \cdots&&&& &&0 \\
M_{2} && M_{1} && -JI_{2} &&\cdots&&&&&& 0\\
0&& JI_{2} && 0  && -hI_{2} &&&& && \vdots\\
0&& 0 && hI_{2}  && 0 &&\ddots&& &&\\
\vdots &&  &&&& \ddots&&\ddots && -JI_{2} && 0\\
0 && && &&&&JI_{2}&& M_{1}^{'}&&-M_{2}^{'}\\
0 && 0 &&&& \cdots && 0&&M_{2}^{'} &&M_{1}^{'}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Each block is a $2\times2$ matrix with complex entries and $I_{2}$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix and $0\neq h,J \in \mathbb{R}$ and I know the following:

1. $M_{1},M_{1}^{'}$ are diagonal matrices
2. $M_{2}$ and $M_{2}^{'}$ are of the form $\begin{bmatrix} h && * \\ 0 && h\end{bmatrix}$

**My question is**: Can we compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors exactly knowing this information?

Comment: What is the matrix $J$ and what is $h$?

Comment: sorry, they are real numbers. made the change

Comment: Its eigenvalues are real . . . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix

Comment: where did you get that from?

Comment: Also, what is the pattern of $JI_2$ and $hI_2$ blocks? Is it one $JI_2$ block, followed by $4n-5$ $hI_2$ blocks, followed by one $JI_2$ block, or is the pattern something else?

Comment: I think I should have been more clear, this is a $2n \times 2n$ matrix with $2 \times 2$ blocks, so the matrix lives in $\mathbb{C}^{4n\times4n}$ and it's n-1 blocks of $JI_{2}$ and n-2 blocks of $hI_{2}$ and they alternate.